# Formula for Excel that Project uses for Duration

Tags: excel-formula

I need the same formula that Microsoft Project has for duration. Need to make this in Excel and SharePoint tasks.

So the column should compare two dates and look like the follow:

```
1 wk
2 wks
3 days
1 day
1 mth
2 mths
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Sounds like `DateDif` with some extra pizzazz. See [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-8235e7c9-b430-44ca-9425-46100a162f38)

Comment: And when @JNevill says `pizzazz` he means a lot of IF() statements to deal with all the eventualities.

Comment: Ugh. yea... now that I look at it... yuck. Anyway you cut it, it's going to be ugly.

Comment: Does project round to the nearest `wk` or `mth`? Like if it's 89 days, does it just say "3 mths"? or does it say "2 mths 3 wks 5 days"?

Answer (score 1):

Doing this with a formula is not something I'm willing to tackle, perhaps someone else feels like dealing with the endless mess of nested `if`s.

Instead, though, a VBA routine that will spit out the number years, months, weeks, and days between two dates should suffice.

```
Function projectDuration(fromdate As Date, todate As Date) As String

    'years
    years = DateDiff("yyyy", fromdate, todate)
    If years > 1 Then
        projectDuration = years & " yrs "
    ElseIf years = 1 Then
        projectDuration = years & " yr "
    End If

    'months
    months = DateDiff("m", DateAdd("yyyy", years, fromdate), todate)
    If months > 1 Then
        projectDuration = projectDuration & months & " mths "
    ElseIf months = 1 Then
        projectDuration = projectDuration & months & " mth "
    End If

    'weeks
    weeks = DateDiff("w", DateAdd("m", months, DateAdd("yyyy", years, fromdate)), todate)
    If weeks > 1 Then
        projectDuration = projectDuration & weeks & " wks "
    ElseIf weeks = 1 Then
        projectDuration = projectDuration & weeks & " wk "
    End If

    'days
    days = DateDiff("w", DateAdd("w", weeks, DateAdd("m", months, DateAdd("yyyy", years, fromdate))), todate)
    If days > 1 Then
        projectDuration = projectDuration & days & " days"
    ElseIf days = 1 Then
        projectDuration = projectDuration & days & " day"
    End If


End Function
```

This is a UDF. Just stick it in a new module in your VBE and then you can use this formula on your worksheet. For instance, if you have the following in your sheet:

```
+---+----------+-----------+
|   |    A     |     B     |
+---+----------+-----------+
| 1 | 1/1/2016 | 2/16/2016 |
| 2 |          |           |
+---+----------+-----------+
```

You can use formula:

```
=projectDuration(A1,B1)
```

And it will spit out `1 mth 2 wks 1 day`.

Comment: You are way too nice.  I started the formula and gave up, not enough time or desire.

Comment: I had this idea to start at years and whittle the range down. Then I had to try it out. Then it worked, so I pasted it here. I have no idea if it will fit OP's needs, but I like it!